# Docusign Radio group pre-fill issues using api

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to pre-select a radio button group using api. however the generated document doesn't seem to have any radio button selected.

Sample:

```
Radio radVal1 = new Radio();
radVal1.setSelected("True");
radVal1.setValue("ChoiceYes");

Radio radVal2 = new Radio();
radVal2.setSelected("False");
radVal2.setValue("ChoiceNo");

List<Radio> radioVals = new ArrayList<Radio>();
radioVals.add(radVal1);
radioVals.add(radVal2);

RadioGroup rgrp = new RadioGroup();
rgrp.setGroupName("RadioGroup4");
rgrp.setRadios(radioVals);

List<RadioGroup> radioGroupTabs= new ArrayList<RadioGroup>();
radioGroupTabs.add(rgrp);

Tabs entityTabs = new Tabs();
entityTabs.setRadioGroupTabs(radioGroupTabs);
```

---

I am using a template with radio buttons with

Group Label : RadioGroup4

Button Values:

ChoiceYes
ChoiceNo

No other conditional logic.

Comment: The group name had a space in between which when corrected works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've resolved your own issue, to make clear for the community the `groupName` string must exactly match the name you pass through the API, otherwise it will not be able to match to the radios.