# Radio groups do not get prefilled when using composite templates

Tags: docusignapi

I cannot add prefilled `radioGroup` values to an envelope when using composite templates

Whatever I do, the template's radio tabs don't get prefilled.

this is my request (with parts omitted) where the text tabs work but radio groups do not:

```
{
  "compositeTemplates": [
    {
      "inlineTemplates": [
        {
          "recipients": {
            "signers": [
              {
                "tabs": {
                  "radioGroupTabs": [
                    {
                      "radios": [
                        {
                          "value": "NL",
                          "selected": "false"
                        },
                        {
                          "value": "FR",
                          "selected": "true"
                        },
                        {
                          "value": "EN",
                          "selected": "false"
                        },
                        {
                          "value": "DE",
                          "selected": "false"
                        }
                      ],
                      "groupName": "Order.ClientLanguage.Radio"
                    }
                  ],
                  "textTabs": [
                    {
                      "value": "21321",
                      "tabLabel": "Order.ClientName"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "clientUserId": "****",
                "inPersonSignerName": "21321",
                "roleName": "Customer",
                "recipientId": "Customer",
                "name": "21321",
                "email": "****"
              }
            ]
          },
          "sequence": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

}
```

another issue that is seemingly the same but doesn't solve my problem:
[Docusign Radio group pre-fill issues using api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458832/docusign-radio-group-pre-fill-issues-using-api)

I also changed the `Data Population Scope` in Docusign's Features preferences to `Envelope`, to no avail.

Comment: Are you using any server Template and using Composite template to prepopulate the PDF values or are you passing any document inside `InlineTemplate`, your code is incomplete so cannot figure out how document is getting added to your envelope? Can you paste complete JSON, after omitting out property values but not property.

Comment: I can see you are adding `"inPersonSignerName": "21321"`, are you trying to do embedded InPerson Signing or embedded signing?

Comment: Your recipientId is invalid. That value needs to be either an integer or a GUID.

Comment: @Drew This was indeed the case, after entering a number there it started working for radioButtonGroups as well,

Is there any reason why textTabs do work in this case, but radioButtons don't?

Answer (score 0):

the recipientId field should be the numeric value of the recipient and must match the way the recipient was initially defined for the envelope. That should fix it.